# Which event should I fire in C# for programming a newly created excel file?

Tags: c#, office-interop

If we want to fire an event when a user hits the save button, we use Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookAfterSave += Application_WorkbookAfterSave;

Similarly, when we want to fire an event when a user opens a saved file, we use
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookOpen += Application_WorkbookOpen;

My question is, which event should we use when a user creates a new file and it is not saved yet. If there's no such event, please tell me anyway of achieving my task of doing some programming as soon as user creates a new excel file.

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.new.aspx

Comment: Events fire once (e.g. once when it's created), and you cannot save a file before creating it, so the statement `creates a new file and it is not saved yet` makes no sense, unless you refer to `opening` as `creating document that already exists` here.

Comment: Have you tried the [`NewWorkbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194565.aspx) event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are interested in the [NewWorkbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837373.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application class in Excel.

```
  ((Excel.AppEvents_Event)Application).NewWorkbook += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_NewWorkbookEventHandler(ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook);


  // the event handler
  void ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("New workbook" + Wb.Name);
  }
```

Comment: It is giving an error that 'Application is a type which is not valid in the given context'

Comment: Got it. Thanks. :-)